# Getting picture orientation from MediaStore.Images.Media

Tags: android, camera, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception, mediastore

I'm not able to run this function correctly

```
private fun getImageOrientation(): Int {
        val imageColumns = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION)
        val imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC"
        val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(photoURI!!, imageColumns, null, null, null)
        if (cursor!!.moveToFirst()) {
            val orientation: Int = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION))
            cursor.close()
            return orientation
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
```

`photoURI` is the variable containing the URI of the picture taken from the camera.
The application causes this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: it.polito.phony.lab1, PID: 3886
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {it.polito.phony.lab1/it.polito.phony.lab1.EditProfileActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Requested column: -1, # of columns: 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4053)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Requested column: -1, # of columns: 0
        at android.database.MatrixCursor.get(MatrixCursor.java:66)
        at android.database.MatrixCursor.getInt(MatrixCursor.java:269)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.getInt(CursorWrapper.java:122)
        at it.polito.phony.lab1.EditProfileActivity.getImageOrientation(EditProfileActivity.kt:193)
        at it.polito.phony.lab1.EditProfileActivity.onActivityResult(EditProfileActivity.kt:171)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6915)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4049)
```

at the line

```
val orientation: Int = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because the cursor doesn't contain the ORIENTATION column.

This might be because you are not querying the correct URI.

Please make sure to call `Uri.fromFile(File(path))` both when sending the MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT for capturing the image and also when setting the pictureURI for the query.